# How to copy folder from http local FTP repository to local computer in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ftp

I'm trying to copy a folder from a `src` path to a `dst` path on my local PC.
The `src` path is a local repository.

```
src=http://moorepo.wdf.ent.corp:8080/static/lit/chrome/googlechromestandaloneenterprise.msi"
dst = c:\users\public\desktop.
```

I have tried several unsuccessful commands like:

```
scp\fileutils.cp_r\def\copy entry.
```

Can someone please assist me with the right command and syntax?

Comment: Look at FTP classes offered by Ruby Core - http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It helps that you showed us the URL and path, but we need to more about what you've tried, including seeing your code attempts and or what you've searched and explanations of why it didn't help. Knowing those things helps us skip over stuff you've tried, or lets us know what you did wrong so we can fix it. As is, a broad question only gets broad answers as we try to narrow it down, which wastes our time. In other words, help us help you by being detailed and explaining, rather than tossing it out there hoping for an answer.

Comment: What do you mean it's a "http local FTP repository"? Is the URL pointing to your machine and you just want to copy from one directory to another locally? Or by "local" do you mean it's on your LAN? Why does this need to be done in Ruby? There are great command-line tools that can do this. Please explain better by putting that information in your question.